# Excel 2010: Saving PERSONAL.XLSB once freezes Excel, saving it twice unfreezes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

(I also asked this question in the Microsoft Community: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/saving-personalxlsb-once-freezes-excel-saving-it/bbeca8fe-e928-423b-8ef1-cdb39be58f7a.)

After editing my VBA code in the PERSONAL.XLSB file (**EDIT**: any hidden workbook), I save it and return to the Excel window - but now it's completely frozen, I can't select cells or anything. Furthermore, if I try to close the workbook while this is going on, Excel crashes ("Microsoft Excel has stopped working").

That's the bad news. The good news is that if I save PERSONAL.XLSB twice instead of just once (like a normal person), everything goes back to normal.

I've never encountered something like this before, and I don't know what to do about it. I thought maybe the PERSONAL.XLSB file was corrupted, so I deleted it, let Excel create a new one and then inserted the old code into it, but nothing changed.

Any help will be appreciated!

#### EDIT 22 Aug:

After making the PERSONAL.XLSB window visible I noticed that some changes I had made while Excel was "frozen" were commited in the PERSONAL.XLSB worksheet. I.e. the "freezing state" seems to be PERSONAL.XLSB being active (but not visible) instead of the current workbook. I tested it, and this happens with every workbook so long as it's hidden. Saving unhidden workbooks works just fine.

Comment: "insert old code" Did you check the code? Maybe there is actually a problem in the code.

Comment: @D_Bester I have added some new details. I will get back to you about the code in a minute.

Comment: @D_Bester I just tried it using a new PERSONAL.XLSB file created by recording a dummy macro, and the same thing happens, so it can't be the code. Do you have any other ideas?